# Как отправить конкретный файл через телеграмм бота (Telebot)

Tags: python, telebot

Есть у меня бот в котором я хочу реализовать отправку конкретного файла (который я тоже выбираю в боте), но к сожалению у меня файл просто не отправляется.
Заранее спасибо за помощь)
P.S. Снизу, конечно, не весь код бота.

```
##########################
logs = open('Logs/log' + time.strftime('%B%d%Y', time.localtime()) + '.txt', 'w+')
logs.close()                                          #создание файла логов
logs = open('Logs/log' + time.strftime('%B%d%Y', time.localtime()) + '.txt', 'a+')
##########################
bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN") # сюда токен
adminid = id # айди админа
def dbupl(message):
    global logs, dbl
    logs.close()
    logs = open('Logs/log' + time.strftime('%B%d%Y', time.localtime()) + '.txt', 'w+')
    logs.close()
    bot.send_message(adminid,'Скачал!\nФайл: ' + 'Logs/' + str(message.text)) 
    dbl = open('Logs/' + str(message.text), 'rb')
    bot.send_document(adminid, str(message.text))
    dbl.close()
    dbl = open('Logs/' + message.text, 'w+')
    dbl.close()
    dbl = open('Logs/' + message.text, 'a+')
    logs = open('Logs/log' + time.strftime('%B%d%Y', time.localtime()) + '.txt', 'a+')                                         
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', '/start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    global logs, myString
        elif message.text == '/dbupload' and message.chat.id == adminid:
        db = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите базу которую хотите скачать (напишите имя файла): \n' + str(os.listdir(path="Logs/")))
        logs.write('Сообщения: ' + message.text + '\nВремя получения: ' + time.ctime() + '\nАйди: '+ str(message.chat.id) +'\nИмя: ' + str(message.from_user.first_name) + '\nФамилия: ' + str(message.from_user.last_name) + '\nНик: @' + str(message.from_user.username)+ '\n\n') 
        bot.register_next_step_handler(db, dbupl)
logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) #логи в консоль
bot.polling(True)
```

Answer (score 1):

пример отправки файла

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    doc = open(r'C:\Users\Violet\PycharmProjects\test_bot\files\file.txt', 'rb')
    bot.send_document(message.from_user.id, doc)
    doc.close()
```